# Entity Framework and base type with same name

Tags: entity-framework-5

I get the following error: The type 'EfTest.Person' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

when running this code:

```
using System.Data.Entity; 
namespace EfTest
{
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new PersonContext())
        {
            db.Persons.Add(new Person());
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class PersonContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; } //people ;)
}

public class Person : EfTest2.Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}namespace EfTest2
{
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

}

can you help and explain why new type can not have same name as its base?

Comment: Have you tried it with different name?

Comment: yes I did, that's why asking about it

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on the keyword ***nested*** in the error. I'm sure taking it out of EfTest2 namespace and keeping the namespace the same will correct this issue. Of course then you must change the base class name from Person to some thing else.

Comment: yes I am aware of this, I know how to work around this problem but I want to know why it is like this

Answer (score 0):

EF has quite complex multi-layered mapping and some of these layers are not directly visible outside. This is a problem of mapping objects into their entity representation in EDM. The point is that EF is not using full class names (including namespaces) but only bare class names so your `Person` classes are in collision and only one can be resolved.

The origin of this behavior is probably in EF 4.0 when it was used to simplify class creation for POCO models and make namespaces independent on the EDMX.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot write the class next to the main session.
You have to separate it to another cs file.
I solved the problem by doing that. Worth a try